# Cannot start local server with Rails via WSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, windows-subsystem-for-linux, puma

I tried updating my Rails app and I believe here is the problem somewhere since I am not able to start the server. I already tried to switch Ruby-Versions and downgrade Rails but somewhere I got stuck and keep getting the same Error.

> .rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:233:in `setsockopt': Invalid argument - setsockopt(2) (Errno::EINVAL)

I believe here comes the problem: The very last line of the log shows issues with Puma.

In [this Gist you can find my Gemfile and Gemfile.lock](https://gist.github.com/dennyscode/32c03c2d57fe7944195997a23df7013f)

```rb
    rails s
    => Booting Puma
    => Rails 6.0.2.1 application starting in development
    => Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
    Puma starting in single mode...
    * Version 4.3.1 (ruby 2.6.3-p62), codename: Mysterious Traveller
    * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
    * Environment: development
    Exiting
    Traceback (most recent call last):
            31: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
            30: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
            29: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
            28: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
            27: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
            26: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
            25: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
            24: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
            23: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
            22: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
            21: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
            20: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
            19: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
            18: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
            17: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
            16: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `perform'
            15: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `tap'
            14: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
            13: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:39:in `start'
            12: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.0.8/lib/rack/server.rb:297:in `start'
            11: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:73:in `run'
            10: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/launcher.rb:172:in `run'
             9: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/single.rb:98:in `run'
             8: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/runner.rb:161:in `load_and_bind'
             7: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:90:in `parse'
             6: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:90:in `each'
             5: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:106:in `block in parse'
             4: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:222:in `add_tcp_listener'
             3: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:222:in `each'
             2: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:223:in `block in add_tcp_listener'
             1: from /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:233:in `add_tcp_listener'
    /home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:233:in `setsockopt': Invalid argument - setsockopt(2) (Errno::EINVAL)
```

Thanks for any help in advance! Denny

Comment: Are you running WSL? I have the same error running rails on WSL :(

Comment: exactly, I should have mentioned of course. I am using wsl.

Answer (score 1):

found the temporal solution.
Example is below:
in file `/home/%username%/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/binder.rb` or in your case `/home/chocolope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/binder.rb`
around row 233:

```rb
   #
    def add_tcp_listener(host, port, optimize_for_latency=true, backlog=1024)
      if host == "localhost"
        loopback_addresses.each do |addr|
          add_tcp_listener addr, port, optimize_for_latency, backlog
        end
        return
      end

      host = host[1..-2] if host and host[0..0] == '['
      # monkey patch starts here
      host = '127.0.0.1'
      port =  3000
      # monkey patch ends here
      s = TCPServer.new(host, port)
#      if optimize_for_latency
        s.setsockopt(Socket::IPPROTO_TCP, Socket::TCP_NODELAY, 1)
 #     end
  #    s.setsockopt(Socket::SOL_SOCKET,Socket::SO_REUSEADDR, true)
      s.listen backlog
      @connected_port = s.addr[1]

      @ios << s
      s
    end
```

now everything works, but we still need the right way to fix this issue

this is a common WSL problem: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1419

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with

WSL: `1`, Ruby: `2.5.0`, Rails: `4.2.1`, and Puma: `3.8.0`

my rails s was working i was getting the follwoing error when ever i send a Get request:

```
Read error: #<Errno::ENOPROTOOPT: Protocol not available - getsockopt(2)>
/home/abr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@helpy/gems/puma-3.8.1/lib/puma/server.rb:124:in `getsockopt'
/home/abr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@helpy/gems/puma-3.8.1/lib/puma/server.rb:124:in `closed_socket?'
/home/abr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@helpy/gems/puma-3.8.1/lib/puma/server.rb:563:in `handle_request'
/home/abr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@helpy/gems/puma-3.8.1/lib/puma/server.rb:425:in `process_client'
/home/abr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@helpy/gems/puma-3.8.1/lib/puma/server.rb:289:in `block in run'
/home/abr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@helpy/gems/puma-3.8.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

I struggle a lot for fixing that issue even I try the above solution but that didn't work either.

at last, I found a simple solution that I need to update my Pum from 3.8 to 3.12+ and it works perfectly for me.